# How to create dynamic number of sections in diffable UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource

I know there is a way to decide the number of sections later on if we use the UICollectionView datasource.

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
```

Just want to know are there any way for diffable datasource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diffable data sources in UIKit and AppKit are declarative.

This means the framework doesn't ***ask*** you for the number of sections, instead you ***tell*** the framework the number of sections while preparing the [`NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsdiffabledatasourcesnapshot).